# Empty "docker images" in Makefile

Tags: docker, makefile

I have a Makefile with some basic docker commands:

```
all: build                                                                                           

build:                                                                                               
    docker build .                                                            

DOCKER_CONTAINERS=$(docker ps -a -q)                                                                 
DOCKER_IMAGES=$(docker images -q)                                                                 

clean:                                                                                               
ifdef $(DOCKER_CONTAINERS)                                                                           
    @echo "Stopping Docker containers..."                                                            
    docker stop $(DOCKER_CONTAINERS)                                                                 
    @echo "Deleting Docker containers..."                                                            
    docker rm $(DOCKER_CONTAINERS)                                                                   
endif                                                                                                

iclean:                                                                                            
ifdef $(DOCKER_IMAGES)                                                                               
    @echo "Deleting Docker images..."                                                                
    docker rmi $(DOCKER_IMAGES)                                                                      
endif
```

And would like to use the last one to clean existing images, I indeed have some images:

```
$ docker images -q
aaa5a74f6006
099dec0df83b
c9889c81a971
bddca31db222
d85328b9bf58
dd6f76d9cc90
```

However, `DOCKER_IMAGES` doesn't seem to be defined in the rule (I doubled checked that later on by displaying it):

```
$ make iclean
make: Nothing to be done for 'iclean'.
```

It works fine with `clean`:

```
$ make clean
Stopping Docker containers...
docker stop $(docker ps -a -q)
f33d30ddc991
35d4d9262460
9ac0507e0b7b
59ff62aa1c0a
2d623e844c23
cb013d3919f4
Deleting Docker containers...
docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)
f33d30ddc991
35d4d9262460
9ac0507e0b7b
59ff62aa1c0a
2d623e844c23
cb013d3919f4
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Do you have a file named `iclean`? Either way, you should define your targets as [PHONY](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Phony-Targets.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see two potential problems:

1. `$(docker images -q)` invokes the make `docker` function... that does not exist. This evaluates as the empty string, even if you have `docker` images. Use:

   ```
   DOCKER_IMAGES = $(shell docker images -q)
   ```
2. `ifdef` does not work as you apparently think:

   ```
   ifdef $(DOCKER_IMAGES)
   ```

   expands variable `$(DOCKER_IMAGES)` and then tests if a variable named as the result of the expansion has a value. Not what you want. You could use:

   ```
   ifdef DOCKER_IMAGES
   ```

   instead. But it is not a very good idea because `DOCKER_IMAGES` could have a value that is just blanks. What you want is test if `$(DOCKER_IMAGES)` is a blank string or not. Use:

   ```
   ifneq ($(strip $(DOCKER_IMAGES)),)
   ```

   Note that the `$(strip...)` is important, it removes leading and trailing blanks such that the test does not pass if `$(DOCKER_IMAGES)` contains only blanks.

Same remarks for your code about the running containers.

Comment: Applying both fixes solves the issue, thanks! However, do you know why it worked with `clean` and not with `iclean`? They are sensibly the same...

Comment: @3kt Honestly, I do not know why it worked with `clean`. The only possibility would be that the value of make variable `DOCKER_CONTAINERS`is the name of another, existing, make variable. And I do not see how `DOCKER_CONTAINERS=$(docker ps -a -q)` could do this.